# setting credentials in gradle via maven-publish

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using gradle v3.4 and have populated properties from a secrets.properties file (passed into project.ext) but when I use the variables in the credentials section, I get an error from nexus complianing about authentication issues which makes me believe the string interpolation is not working correctly.  I can print the variable value just before the credentials section.

**build.gradle**

```
        maven {
            credentials {
println(project.nexusUsername)  //prints the value
                username '${project.nexusUsername}'
                password '${project.nexusPassword}'
            }
            if (project.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
                url "http://nexus.somewhere.com/repository/some-java-snapshot/"
            } else {
                url "http://nexus.somewhere.com/repository/some-java-release/"
            }
        }
```

**Update**
I updated the credentials section above to use double quotes (not single) but that did not solve the issue.  Single quotes are String literals - if you need String interpolation, you need to use double quotes in groovy.

Comment: I modified the single quotes to double quotes but the issue persists

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue was how the properties was specified in the external properties file.  I was using double quotes for the String values in the properties file and that was resulting in authentication failures.  Once I removed the double quotes from the external properties file, I was able to publish to nexus.

**Incorrect external properties file setting**

```
someUsername="someuser"
```

**Correct external properties file setting**

```
someUsername=someuser
```

**build.gradle**

```
publishing {
    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) {
            from components.shadow
            groupId project.group
            artifactId project.artifactId
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username project.someUsername
                password project.somePassword
            }
            if (project.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
                url project.someSnapshot
            } else {
                url project.someRelease
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this works.

Comment: Where & How did you find this docs ?  Gradle DSL Reference is hard to search

Comment: Some docs can be found here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:authentication_schemes

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes denote a String literal without variable expansion;

Please use

`username project.nexusUsername
password project.nexusPassword`

Reference: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_single_quoted_string

Comment: It's hardly a string interpolation issue then; does ```mvn deploy:deploy-file``` work with the given url-s and creds?

Comment: I can switch the variable with the actual value and it works fine - the whole idea is to not use the actual string values inside the build.gradle file - which just is not working.  I am assuming I'm doing something wrong but need to figure out how to debug further